# Are there any other abilities or feats that grant extra benefit from flanking?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Besides the normal +2 to attack rolls and any sneak attack, are there anything in class abilities or feats that gets triggered or give other bonuses when the said character is flanking someone?

Comment: Obvious bonuses are improved chance to hit and damage; there may be other types of bonuses available. Are you interested in *any* benefit to flanking, or just those 2?

Comment: Im interested on extra benefits received from flanking, not the basic flanking bonus or sneak attack.

Answer (score 1):

**Teamwork feats** - there are two teamwork feats in particular that increase the benefits of flanking beyond the normal +2 to hit and allowing sneak attack (with the myriad sneak attack options available through class abilities and feats).

- Outflank (Advanced Players Guide) - flanking bonus to hit increases from +2 to +4
- Enfilading Fire (Ultimate Combat) - bonus of +2 to hit for ranged attacks against an enemy being flanked by allies

Comment: There are others, such as [Precise Strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/precise-strike-combat-teamwork/). Situationally, [Snapping Flank](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/snapping-flank-combat-teamwork), [Topple Foe](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/topple-foe-combat-teamwork) and [Wild Flanking](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/betrayal-feats/wild-flanking-betrayal-teamwork)